# .NET Core exceptions not tracked on Application Insight

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am having an issue with .NET core exception tracking in Application insights. I've tried to implement middleware from here [.Net Core - Azure Application Insights not showing exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217722/net-core-azure-application-insights-not-showing-exceptions) with no luck. There are still no exceptions showing which is really annoying. 500 Error and not knowing what is happening.

Is there any solution for this yet out?

Comment: This middleware already exists. Just follow the instructions and add `app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();` into appropriate place in the pipeline. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/05/19/application-insights-for-asp-net-5-youre-in-control/) for details

Answer (score 0):

This middleware already exists. Just follow the instructions and add `app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();` into appropriate place in the pipeline. See [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/05/19/application-insights-for-asp-net-5-youre-in-control/) for details